# Restrict mod_pagespeed to specific domains on a server

Tags: apache, apache2

If a server hosts the following domains:-

```
http://exampleA.com
http://exampleB.com
http://exampleC.com
```

How is it possible to enable `mod_pagespeed` for only domains `http://exampleA.com` and `http://exampleC.com` **but not** `http://exampleB.com`?

I have read up on the [documentation for domains](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/domains) but not quite sure I can fathom out if this possible to achieve...

I have tried inserting the following into `pagespeed.conf` and restarting Apache but `mod_pagespeed` is still applying to all domains...

```
ModPagespeedDomain http://exampleA.com
ModPagespeedDomain http://exampleC.com
```

Answer (score 4):

After a little digging and playing around with this, I've managed to figure it out and now have a working scenario for `mod_pagespeed` to only work on specific domains (vhosts) on the same server.

My configuration is based on a CentOs 6 build Apache 2 that runs Parallels Plesk Panel.

Create a separate pagespeed conf file and store it in a location that won't be a) automatically overwrote or b) automatically loaded (i.e in the existing `conf` or `conf.d` directories). In my instance, I created `/etc/httpd/myconf` and named the file `vhosts-pagespeed.conf`.

This configuration file will contain the`mod_pagespeed` configuration you wish specific domains to use (you can create as many of these as you like). For example, mine is like:-

```
#https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/configuration#virtual-hosts

<IfModule pagespeed_module>
ModPagespeed on
AddOutputFilterByType MOD_PAGESPEED_OUTPUT_FILTER text/html
ModPagespeedFileCachePath            "/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/"
ModPagespeedFileCacheInodeLimit        500000
ModPagespeedAvoidRenamingIntrospectiveJavascript on
ModPagespeedLibrary 105527 ltVVzzYxo0 //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.1.0/prototype.js
ModPagespeedLibrary 92501 J8KF47pYOq //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js
ModPagespeedLibrary 141547 GKjMUuF4PK //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js
ModPagespeedLibrary 43 1o978_K0_L http://www.modpagespeed.com/rewrite_javascript.js

ModPagespeedEnableFilters extend_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters combine_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_javascript
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters insert_img_dimensions
ModPagespeedEnableFilters move_css_to_head
ModPagespeedEnableFilters lazyload_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters outline_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters flatten_css_imports
ModPagespeedEnableFilters inline_import_to_link
ModPagespeedEnableFilters local_storage_cache
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace
ModPagespeedEnableFilters elide_attributes
ModPagespeedEnableFilters remove_comments

ModPagespeedDisableFilters rewrite_javascript,combine_javascript

ModPagespeedModifyCachingHeaders off

ModPagespeedDomain *
<Location /mod_pagespeed_beacon>
      SetHandler mod_pagespeed_beacon
</Location>
<Location /mod_pagespeed_statistics>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    SetHandler mod_pagespeed_statistics
</Location>
<Location /mod_pagespeed_console>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    SetHandler mod_pagespeed_console
</Location>
<Location /mod_pagespeed_message>
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    SetHandler mod_pagespeed_message
</Location>
<Location /mod_pagespeed_referer_statistics>
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    SetHandler mod_pagespeed_referer_statistics
</Location>
</IfModule>
```

You'll then need to disable the global `mod_pagespeed` and only include the vhost specific pagespeed config on those domains which you wish to enable `mod_pagespeed`.

Navigate to `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf` and create the file `vhost.conf` with the include (this is all this file needs to contain):-

```
Include /etc/httpd/myconf/vhosts-pagespeed.conf
```

Disable global `/etc/httpd/conf.d/pagespeed.conf` by modifying like so:-

```
ModPagespeed off
```

Then restart the server:-

```
service httpd restart
```

Now check that `mod_pagespeed` is enabled on the `domain.com` that you extended the vhost to include the custom pagespeed conf.

If that doesn't work, you may find you need to reconfigure the vhost for `domain.com` with something like:-

```
 /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng --reconfigure-vhost --vhost-name=domain.com
```

Comment: Nicely done! This can likely also be applied to similar or near similar questions and be very helpful to users.

Comment: I hope so, I was sure this must have been possible but surprisingly found very little on the web discussing it. Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes I am surprised what is not covered on the net. Somethings I would think would be obvious cannot be found. Part of it sometimes is over optimization by Goolge- found answer on page 34 or something. ;-) Now it will be on page 1!

Comment: On a side note: mod_pagespeed can also be toggled from the htaccess file

Comment: Thanks for the input @Aznim. I wondered this too, is it as simple as declaring `ModPagespeed off` in the site's `.htaccess` then?

Comment: @zigojacko Your assumption is correct! In our case We have disabled mod_pagespeed globally, and used the htaccess file to enable it selectively for some of our clients (We've got lots of legacy pages and in some cases mod_pagespeed breaks the page). Also the htaccess can be used to selectively enable/disable mod_pagespeed on a folder basis... for example: enable it on the visitor site, disable it on the admin interface.

Comment: Excellent, for a small number of sites on the server, handling it this way would prove far easier I suspect. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use .htaccess files you can simply set `ModPagespeed off` in the `httpd.conf` and then do this in the root `.htaccess` for any domain you want it enabled on:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>

    ModPagespeed on

</IfModule>
```

If you are using Apache 2.4+ you can even use the `<If>` directive for cases where the same `.htaccess` file is used for multiple domains, or for example if you have the `.htaccess` in a Git repository and you use the same one for the production and development sites but want `ModPagespeed on` only for the production site:

```
<IfModule pagespeed_module>

    <If "req('Host') == 'www.example.com'">
        ModPagespeed on
    </If>
    <Else>
        ModPagespeed off
    </Else>

</IfModule>
```